# The command "rm -rf !(a)" doesn't work in bash -c syntax

Tags: linux, bash

There are three files in family dir named 'a' 'b' 'c'. I used "rm -rf !(a)" to delete the 'b' and 'c' files, after run it in bash CLI, it worked fine. As below:

```
xx@xx:~/# ls
a b c
xx@xx:~/# rm -rf !(a)
xx@xx:~/# ls
a
```

However, when I was running it by "bash -c", it threw a syntax error to me, that is as below:[![enter image description here]

```
xx@xx:~/# ls
a b c
xx@xx:~/# bash -c "rm -rf !(a)"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('
bash: -c: line 0:`rm -rf !(a)'
```

Then I added backslash before '!', '(' and ')'. Although, there is not error occur; I found it did not work. As below:

```
xx@xx:~/# ls
a b c
xx@xx:~/# bash -c "rm -rf \!\(a\)"
xx@xx:~/# ls
a b c
```

Could any body can help to clarify this problem?

Comment: Please, do not show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: `rm -rf [^a]` would do if you want to remove all one letter files and directories except `a`. If you want to remove `b` and `c` explicitly: `rm -rf [bc]` ... or `rm -rf b c` ...

Comment: Your interactive shell has the `extglob` option enabled (probably via something like `shopt -s extglob` in an appropriate configuration file). The shell started by `bash -c` does not.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet That doesn't work, because the entire string is parsed before `shopt` is executed, so `extglob` isn't enabled when the non-default syntax is encountered. You would need `bash -O extglob -c '...'` so that the necessary option is enabled on shell startup, *before* the `-c` argument is parsed.

Comment: @chepner Oops, you're right, of course.

Comment: Note: using `rm -rf` to delete files when you are root is a wonderful way to ruin your installation. Even when not root, never, never, never use `rm -rf` to delete files. Imagine that you type `rm -rf ~ /foo` instead of `rm -rf ~/foo`...

Comment: Please c.f. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and edit accordingly.

Comment: @chepner  this also works: `bash -c $'shopt -s extglob\necho !(a)'`

Comment: @pynexj Oh, right, the newline "ends" the current input where the `;` does not.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sorry for my thoughtlessness, already change the original image to text with code format.

Comment: @TedLyngmo May i know the syntax such as if want to remove all files except b and c file in current directory?

Comment: @PaulHodges, Got it! Already correct them.Thanks for your information!

Comment: @YayongDuan I added a possible answer to your question to Paul's answer below.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, thanks for your adding! I have known how to use `grep` or `find` with pipeline symbol to implement reverse removal. Just wonder that why does `!(a)` syntax not work in `bash -c "xxx"`,  already got the answer. However, still thanks for adding the awesome implementation method of find.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `extglob` patterns carelessly.
Don't use "not" logic carelessly.
Don't use *globs* carelessly.

And for all gods' sake, please don't use `rm -fr` as `root` with *anything* other than damned-near paranoia.

If you had anything *besides* `a` in that directory, or in any subdirectory of it, it's gone.

```
$: find
.
./a
./abc
./bar
./bcd
./efg
./efg/hij
./efg/hij/klm
./foo
./x
./y
./y/deleteme
./y/deleteme/stuff

$: bash -O extglob -c 'echo rm -fr !(x)'
rm -fr a abc bar bcd efg foo y
```

Obviously, it grabs everything that is, as you asked, *not `x`*.
As Ted Lyngmo pointed out in his comment above,

> `rm -rf [^a]` would do if you want to remove all **one letter** files and directories except `a`. If you want to remove `b` and `c` explicitly: `rm -rf [bc]` ... or `rm -rf b c` ...

Simple, clear, and specific is virtually always better when it's an option.

#### Added by Ted:

---

> If you want to remove all files except `b` and `c` in the current directory (which is what you asked for in a comment) you could again use `find` with the extension `-maxdepth 1` to only make it search in the current directory:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \! \( -name b -o -name c \) -exec echo {} +
```

> Replace `echo` with `rm -f` if you are sure you want to delete those listed. The `find` version included in [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) has some more extensions making it possible to skip providing the top directory `.` and it also has a `-delete` option to delete files:

```bash
# danger zone below:
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \! \( -name b -o -name c \) -delete
```

---

(Thanks, Ted - I was just coming back to add this, lol)

> Paul Hodegs, you are right, however there is a case that i need keep some specified file or sub-dir in a certain dir, we need to remove the other dirty data in this dir regularly to avoid limited disk no-free case caused by some partners forgetting remove his/her research data in this dir after he or she used. –
> Yayong Duan

Valid, in which case your original question *is* (sort of) a programming question. Be very careful to always assert that you are working in/on the right directory, and careful that maybe you back up your data pretty often against possible errors, but the important thing in that case is that you explicitly list ALL the files you want to keep in the single command to remove everything else.

In my above example, if you wanted to keep `abc` and `bcd`, you'd need `rm -fr $thatDir/!(abd|bcd)`.

Just be super careful with that, and I strongly suggest using a nonprivileged user.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always test your globs (especially anything even minimally complicated) with `echo` or `ls` (etc) before actually applying them with something destructive like `rm`.

Comment: Paul Hodegs, you are right, however there is a case that i need keep some specified file or sub-dir in a certain dir, we need to remove the other dirty data in this dir regularly to avoid limited disk no-free case caused by some partners forgetting remove his/her research data in this dir after he or she used.

Comment: I use `trash` instead of rm because it can recover deleted files in a Trash directory.